# I am trying to make a simple program to go through survey data for a project at school, but it is not working

Tags: python, statistics

The program has pygame imported, but it is not going to be used yet. Here is my code, along with an explanation of what I want it to do:

```
import pygame as pg
import csv
import math
import os
# question class
class question():
    def __init__(self,qst):
        self.qst = qst
        self.dat = []
        print(self.qst)
    # data filter
    def filt(self):
        i = 0
        j = 1
        for i in len(self.dat):
            for j in len(self.dat)/2:
                if self.dat[i][j] == 1:
                    self.dat.pop(i)
                i += 1
                j += 2
        print(self.dat)
    # adding data:
    def ask(self):
        x = True
        y = 1
        n = 2
        Y = 1
        N = 2
        yes = 1
        no = 2
        points = input("how many answers did you get?")
        points = int(points)
        print(points)
        for i in points:
            #get data
            a1 = input("please enter a1 \n")
            a2 = input("please enter a2 \n")
            a = [int(a1),int(a2)]
            self.dat.append(a)
            os.system("cls")
            i += 1
        os.system("cls")
        print(self.dat)
    def search(self):
        print("TODO: make this work")
q1 = question("do you like beans?")

def main():
    q1.ask()
    q1.filt()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have been testing it with made up data. the main problem is that it won't work when I try to use a variable in the for loop in the ask() function in the question class the function is supposed to let me enter data from a sheet. Here is what is returned:

```
> pygame 2.5.2 (SDL 2.28.3, Python 3.11.5)
> Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
> do you like beans?
> how many answers did you get?6
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\math\survey.py", line 51, in <module>
>  main()
>  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\math\survey.py", line 48, in main
>  q1.ask()
>  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\math\survey.py", line 33, in ask
>  for i in int(points):
> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

What am I doing wrong here, and how can I fix it?

Comment: If you want to iterate `points` times you must use [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range): `for i in range(points):` (or `for _ in range(points):` if you are not going to use `i`) and not `for i in points:`, because effectively you cannot iterate over  an integer. Also you must delete `i += 1`, the variable is already incremented by the `for` loop.

Comment: In the `filt` method the same thing happens, but in this case I have a doubt in what this function is supposed to do, because even correcting the problem with `range`, you will get index out of range because the sublists always have two elements and `for j in range(len(len(self.dat)//2)` generate invalid indexes if `self.dat` has more than 4 sublists... In addition there is the problem of deleting items of an iterable at the same time that you iterate over it... If you explain what the function should do in more detail it would be easier to give you some solution.

Comment: each question is technically 2 questions, the actual question, and whether or not the answerer has seen the question before. I am trying to make it so that it deletes an answer if the second value is yes, or 1.

Comment: So, if you have a list like `[[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1]]` after applying `filt` it would be `[[1, 0], [0, 0]]`? Another thing, the user enters as answer always "y"/"Y"/"yes"/"n"/"N"/"no"? I say it because your current code only accepts that the user enters integers, `a = [int(a1),int(a2)]` will fail if `a1` and `a2` are not strings that represent an integer, if you enter for example "y" it will generate an exception.

Comment: @FJSevilla you have the right idea with it also, I actually updated the ask method to make it so that it does accept those variables ("y"/"Y"/"yes"/"n"/"N"/"no").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems in the code, let's go by parts:

### Iterate n times

The cause of the error you show is in the line

```
for i in points:
```

where `points` is an integer and you intend to iterate `points` times. As the error shows you, an integer is not iterable, to do what you want you have to use the builtin `[range`][1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range):

```
for i in range(points):
    # do something
```

or if you are not going to use the variable `i`, by convention it is named using an underscore:

```
for _ in range(points):
    # Do something
```

The line `i += 1` is unnecessary, the variable is already incremented in the `for` loop by iterating over the range.

Another option, less pythonic, is to use a `while` loop:

```
i = 0
while i < points:
    # do something
    i += 1
```

Exactly the same error you have in

```
for i in len(self.dat):
    for j in len(self.dat)/2:
```

where `len` also returns an integer, so you should also use `range` in this case.

### Iterating over the nested list

Even correcting the above, this loop will generate invalid indices:

```
for i in range(len(len(self.dat)):
    for j in range(len(len(self.dat) // 2):
```

`len(self.dat) // 2`, if `self.dat` has for example 6 sublists, returns `3` and the sublists of `self.dat` all have 2 items so `self.dat[i][2]` will be an invalid index.

In any case you should do:

```
for i in range(len(len(self.dat)):
    for j in range(2):
```

### Filtering the list

Another problem is that in your `filt` method you are iterating over a list while removing items from it. Doing this as you do invalidates the indexes generated by the `for`, for example:

```
>>> l = [1, 3, 5]
>>> for i in range(len(l)):
        if l[i] == 3:
           l.pop(i)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  Line 2
    if l[i] == 3:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

When the loop delete the 3 the list remains with a length of 2, and the index 2 (remember that the indexing begins in 0) generated by the last iteration of the cycle is invalid now.

There are several ways to solve this, from using a copy of the list to iterating in reverse order:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for i in range(len(l) - 1, -1, -1):
        if l[i] == 2:
            l.pop(i)
>>> l
[1, 3]
```

Or directly generate a new list with the filtered items, for example, in your case to eliminate the entries whose second answer is `1` you can do:

```
self.dat = [ans for ans in self.dat if ans[1] != 1]
```

which, without using list compression, is equivalent to something like:

```
dat = []
for ans in self.dat:
    if ans[1] != 1:
        dat.append(ans)
self.dat = dat
```

### User input

Another problem in your code is that apparently the user must enter "yes" or "no" as answers, but your code does:

```
a1 = input("please enter a1 \n")
a2 = input("please enter a2")
a = [int(a1), int(a2)].
```

This will generate a `ValueError` if the user enters a string that cannot be converted to an integer. You must validate the input and convert that yes/no to 1/0, for example, using conditionals:

```
a1 = input("please enter a1").lower()
if a1 in ("y", "yes"):
    a1 = 1
elif a1 in ("n", "no"):
    a1 = 0
else:
    print("Invalid input...")
```

or a dictionary mapping the inputs to their internal values, etc.

---

Taking all of the above into account:

```
import os


# question class
class Question:
    def __init__(self, qst):
        self.qst = qst
        self.dat = []
        print(self.qst)

    # data filter
    def filt(self):
        self.dat = [ans for ans in self.dat if ans[1] != 1]
        print(self.dat)

    @staticmethod
    def get_asnswer(msg):
        valid_answ = {
            "n": 0,
            "no": 0,
            "y": 1,
            "yes": 1
            }
        while True:
            user_answ = input(msg)
            if (answ := valid_answ.get(user_answ.lower())) is not None:
                return answ
            print("Invalid answer, try again...")

    # adding data:
    def ask(self):
        points = int(input("how many answers did you get? "))
        print(points)

        for _ in range(points):
            # get data
            a1 = self.get_asnswer("please enter a1 \n")
            a2 = self.get_asnswer("please enter a2 \n")
            self.dat.append([a1, a2])
            os.system("cls")
        print(self.dat)

    def search(self):
        print("TODO: make this work")


def main():
    q1 = Question("do you like beans?")
    q1.ask()
    q1.filt()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```